# Hibernate: @OneToMany - @ManyToOne Entity gets removed, but appears again in collection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a problem and I´m becoming desperate: I remove an item from a collection (List), Hibernate generates the queries and says, that it removes the item - but at the end, it appears again. Before refactoring, everything worked perfectly. Now, everything works as expected, only the removal of items from this one collection causes me a headache:

- spring-boot 1.5.13

Before the refactoring:

I had a list with tasks (Task) in an entity Tour. The task maintained a relationship to its tour as well. So: A Task can have one Tour, and a tour can have multiple tasks.

I was able to remove Tasks from a tour without any problems:
* I set the tour on the task side to null
* removed the task from the list
==> worked perfectly

Out of a sudden - after a refactoring - it stopped working. Only the removal. What did I do: I changed the type of Task to abstract and created a subclass "HandoverTask" (because I want more, different kind of tasks) - @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE).

My overall code works perfectly, only the removal of tasks from a tour does not work. In the Hibernate logs I can see, that Hibernate removes the task from the list - but on a later stage it appears again ( I left out unnecessary attributes):

```
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour{ [.....] tasks=[com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.Task#1001]}
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.HandoverTask{ [.....] tour=com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour#951, [.....] }
[.....] left out select statement
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
o.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry   : Collection dirty: [com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour.tasks#951]
o.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  : Collection found: [com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour.tasks#951], was: [com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour.tasks#951] (initialized)
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 1 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections2018-08-24 12:19:13.898 DEBUG 29430 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour{ [.....] tasks=[]}
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.HandoverTask{ [.....] tour=null [.....]}
org.hibernate.SQL                        : update mhds_task set [.....] tour_id=?, [.....] where task_id=?
[.....] Left out unnecessary attributes
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [10] as [BIGINT] - [null]
[.....] Left out unnecessary attributes
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
```

**First: tasks=[com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.Task#1001]**

**Later: tasks=[]**

You can see - the task is on the list and the tour in the task, after the removal the task list is empty and the tour is null.

Later in the logs I can see, that the list is again propagated with the task entry, while the tour on the task site is still empty:

```
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.Tour{ [.....] tasks=[com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.Task#1001]}
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.HandoverTask{ [.....] tour=null, [.....]}
org.hibernate.SQL                        : update mhds_task set tasks_list_index=? where task_id=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1001]
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
```

And the tasks are back:

***tasks=[com.mhds.backend.domain.entities.task.Task#1001]***

So it causes my unit tests to fail. While debugging I can see, that the entries are removed from the list - but as soon as I´m back in the class that performs the JUnit tests - they are back. I tried already several 'manual' flushes, but the entries are coming back any time.
I cannot find any INSERTS in between the above-mentioned statements or rollbacks, they´re followed by each other.

Task:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(HandoverTaskEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "mhds_task")
public class HandoverTask extends Task{

[...]

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tour_id", nullable = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,    property="id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
@JsonProperty("tourId")
private Tour tour;

public Tour getTour() {
    if (this.tour != null)
        return tour;
    return null;
}

public void setTour(Tour tour) {
    this.tour = tour;
    if (tour == null) {
        this.state = TaskState.open;
    } else {
        this.state = TaskState.scheduled;
    }
}

[...]

}
```

Tour:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mhds_tour")
public class Tour extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

[...]

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "tour", cascade = {  CascadeType.PERSIST })
@OrderColumn(name = "tasks_list_index")
private List<HandoverTask> tasks;

public List<HandoverTask> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}

public void removeTask(HandoverTask task) {
    this.tasks.remove(task);
    // bidirectional
    task.setTour(null);
}

[...]


}
```

The removal happens via the Tour.removeTask method.

Any help/ideas appreciated! I stumbled already over some equals, hashcode problems - but equals is implemented and I cannot relate those problems to my concrete one.

Best regards

Comment: how do you read the tour? is there a transaction? Have you changed something with the transaction handling? I see that there is no orphan removal on the toMany side

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply.

Reading: I request a new instance from the repository:

tour0 = this.tourRepository.findOne(tour0.getId());

Indeed - there´re transactions: There´s a service class that handles the removals, annotated with @Transaction (class level). The whole work happens in this service : this.tourService.removeTaskFromTour(task0.getId(), tour0.getId());

Comment: One more observation: If I remove the flushes/saveAndFlush from the service class and use only "save()", I can see in the logs from the entity printer, that the task is still in the set. 
On the other hand: Hibernate performs the deletion: tour_id=? and the adaption of the task_list_index